# Show that if $C \subseteq A \cup B$, then there are sets $A_1 \subseteq A$ and $A_2 \subseteq B$ such that $A_1 \cup B_1 = C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show that if $C \subseteq A \cup B$, then there exist sets $A_1 \subseteq A$ and $B_1 \subseteq B$ such that $A_1 \cup B_1 = C$

Do I need to treat this question like a biconditional statement?

Comment: Take $A1=C\cap A$ and $B1=C\cap B$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outline: Let $A_1=A\cap C$ and $B_1=B\cap C$. Show, say by element chasing, that $A_1\cup B_1=C$.

Comment: so can I just start off by saying suppose A1 and B1 are the sets that intersect with C?

Comment: I have indicated how to start. The "harder" part (and it is not hard) is to show that if $x\in C$ then $x\in (A\cap C)\cup (B\cap C)$. Here is where we get to use that $C\subseteq  A\cup B$.

Answer (score 2):

Andre is saying that you need to start by looking at elements in C and seeing how those elements are placed in A∪B. For instance, every element in C must be in A, B, or both. Another hint, subsets of C are subsets of A∪B; subsets of C can also be subsets of A or B exclusively.

Comment: By the time you've committed to posting an Answer, you should most likely abandon all reluctance tto actually give a full and useful Answer, for the benefit of future Readers if not the OP.